# Use .htaccess to redirect root to two different directories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm developing a website that has to co-exist with another one on an existing server. I know it's not an ideal situation but for timing reasons we don't really have any choice.

Request coming to the root of the URL have to be routed to the index.html of the new website, and everything else has to go the index.html of the old website (both of the websites are using react so every route goes to index.html).

I've tried to write a `.htaccess` doing this but with no success so far.

Here's an example of how it's supposed to work :

I have two folders, old/ and new/ each containing a website.

if a user goes to `http://example/` -> it's serving content from the `new/` folder.

if a user goes to `http://example/test` -> it's serving content from the `old/` folder.

Below is what I've tried. It redirects `/` to the `new/` folder, but rewrites the URL doing so. Furthermore, as soon as I try to redirect `/*` to the `old/` folder things stop working.

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect requests to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ new [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite the root only to new/index.html
RewriteRule ^$ new/index.html [L]

# Rewrite other URLs to old/index.html
RewriteRule . old/index.html [L]
```

You should rewrite directly to the file that is handling the request. If you rewrite to `new` only - without a trailing slash - then mod_dir will issue an external redirect to append the slash.

NB: This does assume that you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/old/` subdirectory that contains mod_rewrite directives (a front-controller), otherwise *everything* (including static resources) will be rewritten to `/old/index.html`.

> It redirects `/` to the `new/` folder, but rewrites the URL doing so

I think you are using the terms "redirect" and "rewrite" the wrong way round. A "rewrite" is *internal* to the server, the URL does not change. This is what you are doing here... rewriting from root to `/new/index.html` etc.

However, a "redirect" is an *external HTTP redirect* that triggers a 3xx response and a second request to the server.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks for your help and for the clarification on redirect/rewrite (I was indeed using those terms wrong).